# what is the fastest way to use fetch or a faster alternative?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a server where quickfire requests are sent to it from a static app. I previously used fetch to get data from the server, but noticed that is was very slow, often delaying the service by 60ms per request. I need the text from the server. My server is hosted on a free plan, so it goes to sleep. I have to send a http request to my host to start it up, which takes a few seconds. I don't mind the few seconds of loading time, since the server only sleeps after an hour of inactivity, but the delay of 60ms per request really slows the app down. I have been doing this (I cant do await on static apps and I cant do async functions because then I would need to rewrite a lot of stuff in my app):

```
fetch('https://server.freenodejshost.com').then(r=>{
r.text().then(txt=>{
//do something with the info
})
})
```

Is there any way to use fetch faster? Or is there a faster alternative to fetch?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your server or your network, not with how your client is making requests.  Have you pinged the server directly from the client just to see what the raw latency is before even involving your nodejs process?

Comment: You're apparently using very low end server infrastructure.  Not only does it go to sleep, but it is presumably on heavily shared infrastructure (the only way they can afford to offer free stuff) which will never deliver cutting edge performance.  FYI, you can also take the browser completely out of  the equation and send requests with something like CURL to measure client performance without the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the benchmark test below. XHR works faster than fetch in most cases.

**XHR:**

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis');
xhr.onload = () => console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
xhr.send();
```

**fetch:**

```js
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis').then(response => response.json()).then(console.log)
```

*ref: [measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/6254/0/xhr-vs-fetch](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/6254/0/xhr-vs-fetch)*

Comment: Wow, this was helpful, but is xhr the fastest way though? It is decapritated,

Comment: XHR is a native function. It works faster than API's like fetch.

Comment: but is it the fastest option? I am sure that xhr and fetch are not the only ways to implement the function of pulling content from a page.

Comment: no, I don't really know go and want to stick to js. still, how would i get the data to my app  without a fetch or xhr or something else in js?

Comment: It's not clear that your measurethat.net benchmark is accurate because it doesn't appear to actually measure when the response comes back, but rather just how long it takes to send the response.  Plus, the accumulated stats for that benchmark show `fetch()` as a tiny bit faster.  This latency issue is likely governed more by network or server infrastructure than by client coding.